I have designed a separate database file for handling database queries for sqlite database in python but facing issue in execute function
I am working on a sqlite database python based project , to keep the code neat and clean I am passing the values of my form fields along with database name and table name to another python file , whose work is to handle only database queries , I have framed the query everthing is working fine but I am getting error in execute() function.
import sqlite3
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
class Db:
def init(self):
pass
def DbConnection(self ,databaseName, databaseTable, tableColumnValueList):
    try:

        print (databaseName, databaseTable, tableColumnValueList)
        connection = sqlite3.connect (databaseName)

        # Create a cursor object
        cursor = connection.cursor ()

        # Query to get column names
        cursor.execute (f"PRAGMA table_info({databaseTable});")

        # Fetch all results
        columns_info = cursor.fetchall ()

        # Extract and print column names
        column_names = [info[1] for info in columns_info]
        print ("Column names:", column_names)

        w = "?," * (len (column_names) - 1)
        w = w[:-1] + ""
        print (w)

        query = "'INSERT into" + " " + databaseTable + " ("

        # Appending columns name in a query string
        for i in range (1, len (column_names)):
            query += column_names[i] + ","
        query = query[:-1] + ") VALUES(" + w + ")',("

        # Appending columns values in a query string
        for i in range (len (tableColumnValueList)):
            query += str(tableColumnValueList[i]) + ","
        query = query[:-1] + ")"
        print(query)


        cursor.execute(query)
        connection.commit ()
        cursor.close()
        # Close the connection
        connection.close ()

    except Exception as e:
        #QMessageBox.about (self, "Exception", 'Error: "{}"'.format (e))
        print(e)


I if am printing the error then getting the following error :near "'INSERT into customerMasterTable (shopKeeperName,secondaryName,beat,mobileNo,cd) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)'": syntax error

What you have displayed is missing the actual values of the five column entries.

There is a list variable called tableColumnValueList , in this I am receiving the five column values

As per my debugging , I came to conclusion that their is error in sql query formation,as mentioned , it is automatically adding double quotation marks I guess

I think it is more likely the single quote characters at the beginning and end of the SQL statement.

Don't interpolate the values manually - use parameter substitution.  This will handle any quoting automatically, and is good practice even if it does not fix your particular problem.

Problem is resolved , I am sharing the corrected code

query = f"INSERT INTO {databaseTable} ({', '.join (column_names[1:])}) VALUES ({', '.join (['?' for _ in range (len (column_names[1:]))])})"
        cursor.execute (query, tableColumnValueList)

